# Elasticsearch CouchDB results contain wrong documents

Tags: elasticsearch, couchdb

My latest _changes feed shows certain documents (most have been deleted):

```
curl http://localhost:5984/portal_development/_changes
{"results":[
{"seq":1,"id":"_design/all_data_values","changes":[{"rev":"1-39896074fc2b20303012fc2585e965d2"}]},
{"seq":2,"id":"_design/row_by_doc_and_data","changes":[{"rev":"1-92235bc2cd3e146f51aa2010f78a443c"}]},
{"seq":3,"id":"_design/all_rows","changes":[{"rev":"1-37aca3ed7a7bf7c94216b9d02df404b7"}]},
{"seq":4,"id":"_design/all_row_count","changes":[{"rev":"1-747ee2484d9941d8395e2d8e85c0db39"}]},
{"seq":17,"id":"_design/all_data_keys","changes":[{"rev":"5-066eff9f9438f57d9e2572122d4b46b2"}]},
{"seq":19,"id":"test","changes":[{"rev":"2-884e850ed686e019c646ae0bd73d2b86"}]},
{"seq":40,"id":"Document-6","changes":[{"rev":"3-700efed9660e068b49f5638435c56d43"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":41,"id":"Document-7","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":42,"id":"Document-8","changes":[{"rev":"3-b7abbe95207b2eec9900680d3c5e8691"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":43,"id":"Document-9","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":44,"id":"Document-10","changes":[{"rev":"3-a72548bea530b70b4453c761d172af3a"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":45,"id":"Document-11","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":46,"id":"Document-12","changes":[{"rev":"3-06d071684b881f266698199cb7619504"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":47,"id":"Document-13","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":48,"id":"Document-14","changes":[{"rev":"3-0fdc8d9edb45bd96e63bdadefa54a9b1"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":49,"id":"Document-15","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":70,"id":"Document-16","changes":[{"rev":"3-700efed9660e068b49f5638435c56d43"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":71,"id":"Document-17","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":72,"id":"Document-18","changes":[{"rev":"3-b7abbe95207b2eec9900680d3c5e8691"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":73,"id":"Document-19","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":74,"id":"Document-20","changes":[{"rev":"3-a72548bea530b70b4453c761d172af3a"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":75,"id":"Document-21","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":76,"id":"Document-22","changes":[{"rev":"3-06d071684b881f266698199cb7619504"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":77,"id":"Document-23","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":78,"id":"Document-24","changes":[{"rev":"3-0fdc8d9edb45bd96e63bdadefa54a9b1"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":79,"id":"Document-25","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":100,"id":"Document-26","changes":[{"rev":"3-700efed9660e068b49f5638435c56d43"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":101,"id":"Document-27","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":102,"id":"Document-28","changes":[{"rev":"3-b7abbe95207b2eec9900680d3c5e8691"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":103,"id":"Document-29","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":104,"id":"Document-30","changes":[{"rev":"3-a72548bea530b70b4453c761d172af3a"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":105,"id":"Document-31","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":106,"id":"Document-32","changes":[{"rev":"3-06d071684b881f266698199cb7619504"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":107,"id":"Document-33","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":108,"id":"Document-34","changes":[{"rev":"3-0fdc8d9edb45bd96e63bdadefa54a9b1"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":109,"id":"Document-35","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":130,"id":"Document-36","changes":[{"rev":"3-700efed9660e068b49f5638435c56d43"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":131,"id":"Document-37","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":132,"id":"Document-38","changes":[{"rev":"3-b7abbe95207b2eec9900680d3c5e8691"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":133,"id":"Document-39","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":134,"id":"Document-40","changes":[{"rev":"3-a72548bea530b70b4453c761d172af3a"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":135,"id":"Document-41","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":136,"id":"Document-42","changes":[{"rev":"3-06d071684b881f266698199cb7619504"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":137,"id":"Document-43","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":138,"id":"Document-44","changes":[{"rev":"3-0fdc8d9edb45bd96e63bdadefa54a9b1"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":139,"id":"Document-45","changes":[{"rev":"3-b92ab48431c87faa8481863ef1594ae9"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":220,"id":"Document-3831","changes":[{"rev":"9-9f6fa047a80ebdedc881c46bbc66447e"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":221,"id":"Document-3833","changes":[{"rev":"9-ffc51b826e328f209f2a4cf23c638290"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":222,"id":"Document-3835","changes":[{"rev":"9-4b769ddbcfdbc17a0337f708bebdefae"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":223,"id":"Document-3837","changes":[{"rev":"9-f1d695f1203c287cec2d90f9de9f6648"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":224,"id":"Document-3830","changes":[{"rev":"9-a1f7c1e62acd9e9e258bdfc6b1da6134"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":225,"id":"Document-3839","changes":[{"rev":"9-d3c61fd534262b334bb3f8a73c96a8f5"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":226,"id":"Document-3832","changes":[{"rev":"9-356c4df73dec64ffb36bb08415c7d999"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":227,"id":"Document-3834","changes":[{"rev":"9-356c4df73dec64ffb36bb08415c7d999"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":228,"id":"Document-3836","changes":[{"rev":"9-356c4df73dec64ffb36bb08415c7d999"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":229,"id":"Document-3838","changes":[{"rev":"9-356c4df73dec64ffb36bb08415c7d999"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":230,"id":"Document-3840","changes":[{"rev":"9-356c4df73dec64ffb36bb08415c7d999"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":240,"id":"Document-3841","changes":[{"rev":"10-17e2084fdf1966b6ba2a000516595eef"}]}
],
"last_seq":240}
```

However, the Elasticsearch has resulting documents that I have no idea where they come from:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/portal_development/_search?pretty=true -d  '
{

        "from" : 0, "size" : 20,

      "query" : {
         "query_string" : {
           "query" : "2:*"
          }
        }
    }'

{
  "took" : 33,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 53,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "portal_development",
      "_type" : "portal_development",
      "_id" : "Document-3744",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {...
      }, {
      "_index" : "portal_development",
      "_type" : "portal_development",
      "_id" : "Document-3751",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {...
    }, {
      "_index" : "portal_development",
      "_type" : "portal_development",
      "_id" : "Document-3732",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {
    } ]
  }
}
```

What the heck is going on here? What could cause this?

Comment: Did you start with an empty index?

Comment: I did try deleting the elasticsearch couchdb river... but I do come back to this same issue. I'm not sure if that means I went back to an empty index?

Comment: Did you try to delete portal_development index? Removing the river doesn't delete data.

Comment: Oooh... nope, I'll try that. How do you delete the index? By the way, what are some good resources for documentation on this type of stuff? I need to get to know Elasticsearch a little more intimately.

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html